# Join lookup table on lowest-level/most detailed field value first

Tags: sql, sql-server, join

I have two tables that I am trying to left join based on a single field in SQL Server 2014, but the problem is that this single field contains a value which relates to one of four "levels" that appear in separate columns in the main table. The `SalesOrg` field is also part of the key since there can be more than one sales org in both the transactional and lookup tables.

Here's the main transactional table:

```
SalesOrg     PHLevel1    PHLevel2    PHLevel3    PHLevel4    SalesQty
-----------------------------------------------------------------------
AB1          Z000        Y000        X000        V000        20
AB1          Z000        Y000        X000        V001        30
AB1          Z001        Y000        X001        V001        10
AB1          Z001        Y001        X000        V003        45
AB1          Z001        Y001        X000        V004        48
AB1          Z002        Y003        X002        V005        67
```

Here's the lookup table I'm trying to join onto the transactional table:

```
SalesOrg     PH              PHLevel      SalesRep
--------------------------------------------------
AB1          <null>          0            Mr. Pink
AB1          Z000            1            Mr. White
AB1          Z001            1            Mr. White
AB1          Z001Y000        2            Mr. Orange
AB1          Z001Y001        2            Mr. Orange
AB1          Z001Y001X000    3            Mr. Blonde
```

So what should happen is that the "lowest" (i.e. highest `PHLevel`, `3`) should be matched first, i.e.:

```
SalesOrg     PHLevel1    PHLevel2    PHLevel3    PHLevel4    SalesQty    SalesRep
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------
AB1          Z000        Y000        X000        V000        20
AB1          Z000        Y000        X000        V001        30
AB1          Z001        Y000        X001        V001        10
AB1          Z001        Y001        X000        V003        45          Mr. Blonde
AB1          Z001        Y001        X000        V004        48          Mr. Blonde
AB1          Z002        Y003        X002        V005        67
```

Then we need to match level 2 that hasn't already been matched using level 3:

```
SalesOrg     PHLevel1    PHLevel2    PHLevel3    PHLevel4    SalesQty    SalesRep
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------
AB1          Z000        Y000        X000        V000        20
AB1          Z000        Y000        X000        V001        30
AB1          Z001        Y000        X001        V001        10          Mr. Orange
AB1          Z001        Y001        X000        V003        45          Mr. Blonde
AB1          Z001        Y001        X000        V004        48          Mr. Blonde
AB1          Z002        Y003        X002        V005        67
```

Then we need to match level 1 that hasn't already been matched using level 2 or 3:

```
SalesOrg     PHLevel1    PHLevel2    PHLevel3    PHLevel4    SalesQty    SalesRep
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------
AB1          Z000        Y000        X000        V000        20          Mr. White
AB1          Z000        Y000        X000        V001        30          Mr. White
AB1          Z001        Y000        X001        V001        10          Mr. Orange
AB1          Z001        Y001        X000        V003        45          Mr. Blonde
AB1          Z001        Y001        X000        V004        48          Mr. Blonde
AB1          Z002        Y003        X002        V005        67
```

Finally, for any remaining items, we need to check level 0, which is the default for "unmatched" entries:

```
SalesOrg     PHLevel1    PHLevel2    PHLevel3    PHLevel4    SalesQty    SalesRep
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------
AB1          Z000        Y000        X000        V000        20          Mr. White
AB1          Z000        Y000        X000        V001        30          Mr. White
AB1          Z001        Y000        X001        V001        10          Mr. Orange
AB1          Z001        Y001        X000        V003        45          Mr. Blonde
AB1          Z001        Y001        X000        V004        48          Mr. Blonde
AB1          Z002        Y003        X002        V005        67          Mr. Pink
```

It is no problem if a concatenated field is created in the transactional table to make it easier to match the lookup table.

I am not sure if it would be advantageous to expand the lookup table so that the `PH` field contains "fully-qualified" values (i.e. so that `PH` always contains `PHLevel1`/`PHLevel2`/`PHLevel3`/`PHLevel4` values, e.g. `Z001Y000X001V001`) but this could then make the lookup table huge and then possibly slow down the join (since the transactional table can contain perhaps a million rows).

I am not sure how to start with this, since I've seen other examples with hierarchies, but the lookup table is not exactly a hierarchy - are there any elegant solutions in SQL please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I get a little anxious when I see code like this, but in your situation, it seems to reflect the real requirements, assuming you aren't able to change the underlying structure of your tables:

```
select      t.*,
            SalesRep = coalesce(l4.SalesRep, l3.SalesRep, l2.SalesRep, l1.SalesRep, l0.SalesRep)
from        @transactionals t
left join   @lookup l4 on t.SalesOrg = l4.SalesOrg and l4.PH = t.PHLevel1 + t.PHLevel2 + t.PHLevel3 + t.PHLevel4 
left join   @lookup l3 on t.SalesOrg = l3.SalesOrg and l3.PH = t.PHLevel1 + t.PHLevel2 + t.PHLevel3
left join   @lookup l2 on t.SalesOrg = l2.SalesOrg and l2.PH = t.PHLevel1 + t.PHLevel2 
left join   @lookup l1 on t.SalesOrg = l1.SalesOrg and l1.PH = t.PHLevel1 
left join   @lookup l0 on t.SalesOrg = l0.SalesOrg and l0.PH is null
```

---

After a little more consideration, I think another strategy will work.  As you suspected, you can concatenate the levels in the transactionals table.  Then you can match based on a like statement.  Of course, that will get you too many matches, so you use a windowed function to find the maximum phLevel between matches.  And then query where the phLevel equals the max.

```
with

    leadMatches as (

        select      t.*, 
                    l.SalesRep,
                    l.PHLevel,
                    maxPhLevel = max(l.phLevel) over (partition by ap.ph)
        from        @transactionals t
        cross apply (select PH = PHLevel1 + PHLevel2 + PHLevel3 + PHLevel4) ap
        join        @lookup l on t.SalesOrg = l.SalesOrg and ap.ph like isnull(l.ph,'') + '%'

    )

    select      m.SalesOrg, m.PHLevel1, m.PHLevel2, m.PHLevel3, m.PHLevel4, 
                m.SalesQty, m.SalesRep
    from        leadMatches m
    where       PHLevel = maxPhLevel
```

Answer (score 1):

This looks like an opportunity for `apply`:

```
select t.*, l.salesrep
from transactional t outer apply
     (select top (1) l.*
      from lookup l
      where l.ph in (t.PHLevel + t.PHLevel2 + t.PHLevel3, t.PHLevel + t.PHLevel2, t.PHLevel) or
            l.ph is null
      order by l.phlevel desc
     ) l;
```

You can easily add `PHLevel4` to the search list.  Part of your question suggests that you want to include it, but it is not in the detailed example.